# Swapping column values based on column conditions (Pandas DataFrame)

Tags: python, pandas

The DataFrame has two columns `A` and `B` of integers.

```
a        b
1        3
4        2
2        0
6        1
...
```

I need to swap in the following way:

```
if df.a > df.b:
    temp = df.b
    df.b = df.a
    df.a = temp
```

expected output:

```
a        b
1        3
2        4    <----
0        2    <----
1        6    <----
```

Basically always having in column A the smaller value of the twos.

I feel I should use `loc` but I couldn't find the right way yet.

Answer (score 7):

```
In [443]: df['a'], df['b'] = df.min(axis=1), df.max(axis=1)

In [444]: df
Out[444]:
   a  b
0  1  3
1  2  4
2  0  2
3  1  6
```

or

```
pd.DataFrame(np.sort(d.values, axis=1), d.index, d.columns)
```

Answer (score 6):

Using `np.where` you can do

```
In [21]: df.a, df.b = np.where(df.a > df.b, [df.b, df.a], [df.a, df.b])

In [23]: df
Out[23]:
   a  b
0  1  3
1  2  4
2  0  2
3  1  6
```

**Or**, using `.loc`

```
In [35]: cond = df.a > df.b

In [36]: df.loc[cond, ['a', 'b']] = df.loc[cond, ['b', 'a']].values

In [37]: df
Out[37]:
   a  b
0  1  3
1  2  4
2  0  2
3  1  6
```

**Or**, `.apply(np.sort, axis=1)` if you need smaller `a` values and larger `b`

```
In [54]: df.apply(np.sort, axis=1)
Out[54]:
   a  b
0  1  3
1  2  4
2  0  2
3  1  6
```

Answer (score 3):

Seeing the methods proposed by @JohnGait and @MaxU, I did a small speed comparison.

```
arr = np.random.randint(low = 100, size = (10000000, 2))

# using np.where
df = pd.DataFrame(arr, columns = ['a', 'b'])
t_0 = time.time()
df.a, df.b = np.where(df.a > df.b, [df.b, df.a], [df.a, df.b])
t_1 = time.time()

# using df.loc
df = pd.DataFrame(arr, columns = ['a', 'b'])
t_2 = time.time()
cond = df.a > df.b
df.loc[cond, ['a', 'b']] = df.loc[cond, ['b', 'a']].values
t_3 = time.time()

# using df.min
df = pd.DataFrame(arr, columns = ['a', 'b'])
t_4 = time.time()
df['a'], df['b'] = df.min(axis=1), df.max(axis=1)
t_5 = time.time()

# using np.sort
t_6 = time.time()
df_ = pd.DataFrame(np.sort(arr, axis=1), df.index, df.columns)
t_7 = time.time()

t_1 - t_0 # using np.where:  5.759037971496582
t_3 - t_2 # using .loc:      0.12156987190246582
t_5 - t_4 # using df.min:    1.0503261089324951
t_7 - t_6 # 0.20351791381835938
```

Although second approach is the fastest approach, the practical gain is insignificant. I am adding it here for pedantic reasons. I didn't include the sort method as I am convinced that's going be a lot slower.

**EDIT**
I had wrongly reported the computation time of `np.where` due to a mistake I made. Corrected that (turns out its the slowest of the lot!) and added another method (following @MaxU's comment)

Comment: Nice comparison! +1. Could you please add timing for `pd.DataFrame(np.sort(d.values, axis=1), d.index, d.columns)` ?

Answer (score 3):

**Solution**
It's as simple as

```
df.values.sort(1)

df

   a  b
0  1  3
1  2  4
2  0  2
3  1  6
```

---

**What Happened**
I can sort a `numpy.array` in place with its `sort` method.  I pass the parameter `axis=1` to indicate that I want to sort along the first axis (row wise).  The `values` attribute of a dataframe accesses the underlying `numpy` array.  So `df.values.sort(1)` sorts the underlying values in place row wise... done.

---

We can be a bit more explicit with

```
df.values[:] = np.sort(df.values, 1)
```

This allows us a lot of flexibility to perform this over subsets of columns or reverse sort

```
df.values[:, ::-1] = np.sort(df.values, 1)
```

Comment: This is brilliant !